# Where can I get aerial maps for offline use?

Tags: aerial-photography, offline

I'm looking for somewhere I can get aerial map files for exclusive offline use. Essentially I need aerial files (JP2K, GeoTIFF, etc.) that can be purchased or acquired and hosted on a private offline server.

I have used NAIP aerial files in a past and they have worked great but they don't have coverage in the area I am interested in. I need the files to have at least the equivalent resolution as NAIP. It also can't be a subscription service it needs to be a one time payment to acquire the files that I need.

Preferred resolution is equivalent to NAIP so 1-meter ground sample distance (GSD), I would like the files to be <5 years old but that can be a little flexible, and the area of interest is Aberdeen Proving Grounds outside of Baltimore.

Comment: Could you expand on which area you need, which resolution would be preferred, how old the data can be and what channels you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erik, I've expanded my question but am not sure what you mean by channels?

Comment: Channels = color bands (Red, Green, Blue, Near IR, etc)

Comment: Oh okay, I just need full color so Red, Green, and Blue.

Comment: NAIP should have wall to wall coverage in the US. What areas do you need coverage?

Comment: @Aaron Not always. Certain sensitive areas are omitted.

Comment: @Bjorn you are right, I see the OP is interested in one of those sensitive areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The State of Maryland has leaf-off orthoimagery available for download for no cost that is refreshed on a regular cycle. See https://imap.maryland.gov/Pages/imagery-download.aspx for more information. It will be higher resolution than NAIP.
\

Comment: Lots of other states do as well...